# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker container port mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have question-related to port mapping on Elastic Beanstalk multiple Docker-container-env.

My Dockerrun.aws.json looks like this:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "web",
      "image": "exampleimage",
      "hostname": "web",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And my web dockerfile look like this:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
# at the end its a nginx images
```

Does this mean my docker container running on port 80, and I make it on host port 3000?

If on my AWS Elastic Beanstalk the endpoint is like

**url-something-like-this-xxxx.com**

How can I access the container?

**url-something-like-this-xxxx:3000.com**. ??

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for accessing a different port other than then one specified by the protocol is ://: 
Examples

Accessing a website over http on port 3000

http://some-url.com:3000

Accessing a website over https on port 8443

https://some-url.com:8443

Also make sure the security group attached to your instance or load balancer allows access on port 3000 from your IP address or 0.0.0.0/0 if you want it to be public

Link to guide on updating security groups.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#AddRemoveRules